# GNOME 3.30.2 lags when laptop is disconnected from power

Tags: gnome3

I have Acer Nitro 5 the AMD ryzen 5 2500U version and the problem im facing is that i installed Antergos and choose GNOME as DE. When the laptop is connected to AC power its Okay and it runs OK. But once the AC power is disconnected the GNOME DE starts to lag when entering Application Menu. And in games like Skyrim the fps i get is about 25-30 without AC power and with AC power i get 40-50 fps which is a huge difference.

Then i installed i3 and configured it. Then i tried running Skyrim without AC power and to my suprise it run at 40-50 fps. When i connected AC power fps didnt change.

So im guessing this is some GNOME power saving feature that does this.

And yes i disabled BIOS cpu frequency limiting and switched to new amdgpu DC code. Running latest MESA 18.3

Comment: It seems to be GNOME power manager fault as i tried running cinnamon desktop as friend suggested and games were running OK even without AC power. Will probably file a bug on GNOME power manager.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that Antergos doesnt install gnome-power-manager as dependency to GNOME and as a resoult it lags. Installing gnome-power-manager fixes this issue and GNOME runs smooth on battery.